# What is the white spot on my Bearded Dragon's head? It does not look like shedding skin

Tags: reptiles, lizards, skin-condition, bearded-dragon

[image]

This white spot is much thicker than shedding skin and seems to be on his eyelid as well. Could it be a fungus?